# 2018 Subaru XV oil overfill

Tags: subaru

[image: So far 5000 miles. Oil level is the same since I got the car new from the dealership. After the first service they refilled it up to the same level.]

Is this normal? Isn’t the 2 dots are low-full?

Why did the dealership overfill it twice up to the twist?

Comment: Are you checking the oil level the proper way - pulling the dipstick, wiping it off, then re-checking?

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the dots. However did you measure the oil when the engine is cold and level? If the engine is hot there are some oils that expand quite a lot when hot. Getting this measurement on hot oil might be right, also if the car isn't level it can show wrong measurements. If you measured the oil while engine is cold and level I suggest you to talk to the dealer and stop drive the car until you talk with the dealer.

Comment: It’s the same. Regardless of the temperature.

Comment: You should speak with the dealer then